# How do I go from GameObject ID to an actual GameObject when Instantiating?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloning

So I'm working on a save system for my app, and I'm trying to store objects in a GameObject array like so:

`public GameObject[ ] entriesInScene;`

When I store GameObject in the array it stores the GameObject ID. When I try and instantiate the object later on in the code using this if loop:

```
foreach (GameObject go in saveObject.entriesInScene)
      {
        Debug.Log(go);
        GameObject entry = Instantiate(go, position, Quaternion.identity);
        entry.transform.SetParent(null);
        entry.transform.SetParent(scroll.transform);
        entry.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
      }
```

It give es me an error of `MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.`

Does Anyone know how to fix this or know how to get the GameObject from the ID to make the instantiate work?

Comment: Could you show us more context of your code? ... In a `public GameObject[ ] entriesInScene;` you store serialized instances of `GameObject` .. if these are destroyed .. well then they are gone ... What exactly do you reference there and how?

Comment: Unfortunately, saving/loading in Unity can't be done like this.  Once you've stopped your game or exited the scene where your saved game object existed, that object no longer exists so you can't instantiate from it.  To do what you're trying to do, you'll need to figure out which prefab your game object was instantiated from, and then get a reference to that prefab and pass that into `Instantiate`

Answer (score 0):

Through Unity you won't be able to save entire GameObjects directly through serialization as far as I know. My approach to a similar problem with implementing a save system was to have each object type stored as a prefab, and then I'd save the important values itself in my script (an example being a microwave prefab that a user could place, but I'd store the Vector3 for the position). In most cases you should be able to just store the values that change between instances of a prefab.